# Determining whether two events are independent with an arbitrary CDF

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a random variable, $v$, distributed with CDF $G$, on $[\underline{v}, \overline{v}]$. Is the probability that $v\geq a\in[\underline{v}, \bar{v}]$ independent of the probability that $v\geq a-x$, where $x$ is some real number? I am inclined to think that it is not, as if $v\geq a-x$, then $v$ is effectively distributed on $[a-x,\bar{v}]$ and so the probability that $v\geq a$ changes. Thank you.

Comment: Yes the statement is false in general, but to answer this completely you will need to consider the sign of $x$ - The statement is true when $x$ is non-negative; when $x$ is negative, whether $a = \overline{v}$ which will make the statement true; and when $x$ is negative, whether $G(a-x) = G(a)$ which also make it true. You write down the definition of independence, and note that for real number $a, b, c$ with $b > c$, we have $a > b$ and $a > c$ implies $a > b$

Comment: @BGM thank you. So if x is non-negative, then $Pr(v\geq a-x \hspace{1mm} and \hspace {1mm} v\geq a)=(1-G(a-x))(1-G(a))$?

Comment: Sorry my previous comment is wrong. There are trivial case to make the statement true, only when $a - x \notin [\underline{v}, \overline{v}]$